# Unable to add foreign keys manually in Entity Framework 4

Tags: foreign-keys, entity, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

So I have a sql server 2008 database with 9 tables in them, they don't have any set relationships but is still used as if they have it, this however makes it so that I cant import the relationships when importing the models from the database.

Now, when trying to add an association between two tables work but when I want to point tb1.Id -> tb2.fkid it forces tb1.Id -> tb2.Id instead, I'm unable to choose anything else besides Id in both tables and I cant delete them either (from the menu after clicking the association line between the tables).

So is it possible to make these "fake" relationships?
if so what am I missing?

Comment: This works for me.
1. Select association in model designer.
2. Select "Referntial constraint" property.
3. Change "Dependent property" to fkid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more looking into it I found the answer, clicking on the association line and choose table mapping, then I started to fiddle around and it enabled me to choose the right column.